# Gradle multi project build with applied compile project() dependency for all subprojects

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a multi project gradle build and I would like to apply one of the subprojects as dependecy for all other subprojects.

That is, if I specify:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(":my-shared-subproject")
}
```

in all relevant build.gradle files for each subproject, it works. I if instead do:

```
subprojects { project ->
    dependencies {
        if(project.name != 'my-shared-subproject') {
            compile project(":my-shared-subproject")
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle gets angry and throws the followin error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-project'.
> Could not find method call() for arguments [:my-shared-subproject] on project ':my-other-subproject' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Am I wrong in thinking this should be possible? If not - what am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `project` parameter from `subprojects`

```
subprojects {
    dependencies {
        if(project.name != 'my-shared-subproject') {
            compile project(":my-shared-subproject")
        }
    }
}
```